# Provisioning Profile error in Xcode 11 beta

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I had been building my app in Xcode 10, and Fastlane had been managing all the provisioning profiles and certificates and everything.

Having put iOS 13 beta on my phone, I installed Xcode 11 beta, and now I'm getting the error: "Provisioning profile "match Development com.myapp.bundleId" doesn't include signing certificate "Apple Development: My Name (ADFGLAUDFHB)".

I'm afraid to change anything at all, lest it mess up my magical Fastlane setup or anything. Hoping someone knows what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Fastlane supports Xcode 11 provisioning-profiles with version 2.132.0 https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/releases/tag/2.132.0

To generate new provisioning profiles you have to nuke the existing one and generate new profiles with the flag `generate_apple_certs` like this

```
fastlane match development --generate_apple_certs
```

or in case of usage inside of a fastfile with somthing like this:

```
 match(app_identifier: [ENV["APP_ID_STAGING"]], type: "development", generate_apple_certs: true)
```